# CSV File Reader Project

Tags: java, mvc, swing, csv

I'm trying to focus on learning so I can get an entry level position and the best way for me to learn right now is to have someone review and provide areas of improvement. This project isn't entirely complete but almost. I am going to include the code for some of the classes but not all of them. Just a few button actions left to finish. All criticism is welcomed.

```
public class CreateAndShowUI {

  public static void createUI() {

    Model model = new Model();

    MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel(model, new CSVFileController(model));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel.getMainPanel());
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1100, 550));
    frame.addMouseListener(new ApplicationMouseAdapters.FrameMouseAdapter());
    frame.addMouseMotionListener(new ApplicationMouseAdapters.FrameMouseMotionListener(
            frame));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static final Font getHeaderFont() {
    return new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 16);
  }

  public static final Font getFont() {
    return new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 14);
  }

  public static final Font getTableFont() {
    return new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 16);
  }

  public static final Color getButtonColor() {
    return new Color(230, 230, 230);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    createUI();
  }
}
```

The `MainPanel` Class which basically creates the main `JPanel` for the `JFrame`. This `JPanel` has two child panels and one menu bar.

```
public class MainPanel {

  private Model model;

  private CSVFileController controller;

  private JPanel mainPanel;

  private Dialog dialog;

  private MenuBar menuBar;

  private ButtonPanel buttonPanel;

  private JScrollPane buttonScrollPane, listScrollPane;

  private JTable table;

  private JLabel search;

  private JTextField searchTF;

  private JButton xButton;

  public MainPanel(Model model, CSVFileController controller) {
    this.model = model;
    this.controller = controller;
    createMainPanel();
  }

  private void createMainPanel() {

    mainPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "", "[]13[]"));

    dialog = new Dialog();

    table = new JTable(new ProductTableModel());
    setTableColumnWidth(table.getModel());
    table.getTableHeader()
            .setPreferredSize(
                    new Dimension(table.getColumnModel()
                            .getTotalColumnWidth(), 48));
    table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
    table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    table.getTableHeader().setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getFont());
    table.setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getTableFont());
    table.addMouseListener(new ApplicationMouseAdapters.TableMouseAdapter(
            dialog, table.getModel(), controller));
    setTableEditorFont(table);

    menuBar = new MenuBar();
    mainPanel.add(menuBar.getMenuBar());

    search = new JLabel("Search");
    mainPanel.add(search, "cell 0 0, gap 10px");

    searchTF = new JTextField("", 30);
    mainPanel.add(searchTF, "cell 0 0");

    xButton = new JButton(new CloseAction("X"));
    xButton.setFocusable(false);
    xButton.setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getFont());
    xButton.setBackground(new Color(158, 7, 7));
    xButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    mainPanel.add(xButton, "cell 0 0, gap 283px, wrap");

    buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel();
    buttonScrollPane = new JScrollPane(buttonPanel.getButtonPanel(),
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    buttonScrollPane.setViewportView(buttonPanel.getButtonPanel());
    buttonScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 990));
    mainPanel.add(buttonScrollPane);

    listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    listScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850, 990));
    mainPanel.add(listScrollPane, "cell 0 1");
  }

  public JPanel getMainPanel() {
    return mainPanel;
  }

  public JPanel getButtonPanel() {
    return buttonPanel.getButtonPanel();
 }

  public JTable getTable() {
    return table;
  }

  public JMenuBar getMenuBar() {
    return menuBar.getMenuBar();
  }

 public final void setTableEditorFont(JTable table) {

    DefaultCellEditor editor = (DefaultCellEditor) table
            .getDefaultEditor(Object.class);
    Component component = editor.getComponent();
    component.setFont(table.getFont());
    editor.setClickCountToStart(1);
  }

  public final void setTableColumnWidth(TableModel tableModel) {

    final TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();

    if (tableModel.getColumnCount() == 6) {
        columnModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(200);
        columnModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(300);
        columnModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(80);
        columnModel.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(75);
        columnModel.getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(80);
        columnModel.getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(75);
    }
 }

 public class ButtonPanel {

    private JPanel panel;

    public ButtonPanel() {
        panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
        addButtons();
    }

    private void addButtons() {

        List<Supplier> supplierList = model.getSuppliers();

        for (Supplier supplier : supplierList) {
            JButton button = new JButton(
                    new SupplierButtonActions.ShowSupplierProductsAction(
                            supplier.getName(), getTable(), model));
            button.setFocusable(false);
            button.setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getFont());
            button.setBackground(CreateAndShowUI.getButtonColor());
            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(230, 30));
            button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            panel.add(button, "wrap");
        }
    }

    public JPanel getButtonPanel() {
        return panel;
    }
  }

  public class MenuBar {

      private JMenuBar menuBar;

      private JMenu application, suppliers, orders;

      private JMenuItem viewOrders, newSupplier, addProduct, close;

      public MenuBar() {
        createMenuBar();
      }

      private void createMenuBar() {

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        close = new JMenuItem(new CloseAction("Close"));
        close.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        close.setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getHeaderFont());

        application = new JMenu("Application");
        application.setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getHeaderFont());
        application.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 70));
        application.add(close);
        menuBar.add(application);

        newSupplier = new JMenuItem(
                new DialogActions.AddSupplierPanelAction(dialog, "New"));
        newSupplier.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        newSupplier.setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getHeaderFont());

        addProduct = new JMenuItem(new DialogActions.AddProductPanelAction(
                dialog, model, "Add Products"));
        addProduct.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
        addProduct.setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getHeaderFont());

        suppliers = new JMenu("Suppliers");
        suppliers.setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getHeaderFont());
        suppliers.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 70));
        suppliers.add(newSupplier);
        suppliers.add(addProduct);
        menuBar.add(suppliers);

        viewOrders = new JMenuItem("View");
        viewOrders.setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getHeaderFont());
        viewOrders.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));

        orders = new JMenu("Orders");
        orders.setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getHeaderFont());
        orders.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 70));
        orders.add(viewOrders);
        menuBar.add(orders);
      }

      public JMenuBar getMenuBar() {
        return menuBar;
      }
  }
}
```

The `KeywordPanel` class which is one of the panels for `JDialog`. This panel is added dynamically to a dialog based on a specific action taken by the user.

```
 public class KeywordPanel {

  private CSVFileController controller;

  private Product product;

  private Dialog dialog;

  private JPanel keywordPanel;

  private JTextField[] textFields;

  private JLabel searchLbl;

  private JButton close, remove;

  public KeywordPanel(CSVFileController controller, Dialog dialog,
        Product product) {
    this.controller = controller;
    this.product = product;
    this.dialog = dialog;
    createKeywordPanel();
  }

  public void createKeywordPanel() {

    keywordPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());

    searchLbl = new JLabel("KeyWords");
    searchLbl.setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getFont());
    keywordPanel.add(searchLbl, "wrap");

    textFields = new JTextField[] { new JTextField(""), new JTextField(""),
            new JTextField(""), new JTextField(""), new JTextField("") };
    for (JTextField textField : textFields) {
        textField.setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getFont());
        textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(242, 30));
        keywordPanel.add(textField, "wrap");
    }

    remove = new JButton(new KeywordPanelController.RemoveAction("Remove",
            controller, product));
    remove.setBackground(CreateAndShowUI.getButtonColor());
    remove.setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getFont());
    keywordPanel.add(remove);

    close = new JButton(new KeywordPanelController.SaveAndCloseAction(
            "Save & Close", controller, dialog, product, textFields));
    close.setBackground(CreateAndShowUI.getButtonColor());
    close.setFont(CreateAndShowUI.getFont());
    keywordPanel.add(close, "cell 0 6, gapx 30px");
}

public void setCategoryTextFields(int index, String category) {
    textFields[index]
            .addMouseListener(new KeywordPanelController.TextFieldMouseAdapter(
                    textFields[index]));
    textFields[index].setEditable(false);
    textFields[index].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    textFields[index].setText(category);
  }

  public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
    keywordPanel.setLocation(x, y);
  }

  public JPanel getKeywordPanel() {
    return keywordPanel;
  }
}
```

Main model for the application:

```
public class Model {
  private Map<Supplier, List<Product>> supplierProductList;

  private List<Product> productList;

  public Model() {
    this.supplierProductList = new TreeMap<Supplier, List<Product>>();
  }

  public void addSupplier(Supplier supplier) {
    if (!supplierProductList.containsKey(supplier)) {
        this.supplierProductList.put(supplier, new ArrayList<Product>());
    }
  }

  public ArrayList<Supplier> getSuppliers() {
    return new ArrayList<Supplier>(supplierProductList.keySet());
  }

  public void addProduct(String name, Product product) {
    for (Supplier supplier : supplierProductList.keySet()) {
        if (supplier.getName().equals(name)
                && !supplierProductList.get(name).contains(product)) {
            this.productList = supplierProductList.get(name);
            this.productList.add(product);
            this.supplierProductList.put(supplier, productList);
        }
    }
  }

  public void addProductList(Supplier supplier, List<Product> productList) {
    this.supplierProductList.put(supplier, productList);
  }

  public ArrayList<Product> getProducts(String name) {
    for (Supplier supplier : getSuppliers()) {
        if (supplier.getName().equals(name))
            return new ArrayList<Product>(supplierProductList.get(supplier));
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

This is the `CSVFileController` class. This is used to update the model and the files based on user interaction with the view.

```
public class CSVFileController {

  private Model model;

  private BufferedReader reader;

  private BufferedWriter writer;

  private String line;

  public CSVFileController(Model model) {
    this.model = model;
    this.reader = null;
    this.writer = null;
    this.line = "";
    updateModel();
  }

  public void updateModel() {
    List<Supplier> suppliers = new ArrayList<Supplier>();

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Suppliers.csv"));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] dataArray = line.split(",");
            suppliers.add(new Supplier(dataArray[0], Integer
                    .parseInt(dataArray[1])));
        }

        for (Supplier supplier : suppliers) {

            List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(supplier.getName()
                    + ".csv"));

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] dataArray = line.split(",");

                if (dataArray.length == 6) {
                    productList.add(new Product(supplier, dataArray[0],
                            dataArray[1], Integer.parseInt(dataArray[2]),
                            Integer.parseInt(dataArray[3]), Double
                                    .parseDouble(dataArray[4]), Integer
                                    .parseInt(dataArray[5])));
                } else {

                    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int x = 6; x < dataArray.length; x++) {
                        categories.add(dataArray[x]);
                    }

                    productList.add(new Product(supplier, dataArray[0],
                            dataArray[1], Integer.parseInt(dataArray[2]),
                            Integer.parseInt(dataArray[3]), Double
                                    .parseDouble(dataArray[4]), Integer
                                    .parseInt(dataArray[5]), categories));
                }
            }

            model.addProductList(supplier, productList);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeReader(reader);
    }
  }

  public void adjustProductCategories(Product product) {
    List<Product> supplierProductList = model.getProducts(product
            .getSupplier().getName());

    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(product.getSupplier()
                .getName() + ".csv"));

        for (ListIterator<Product> iterator = supplierProductList
                .listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

            Product prod = iterator.next();

            if (prod.getId() == product.getId()) {
                iterator.remove();
                iterator.add(product);
                model.addProductList(product.getSupplier(),
                        supplierProductList);
            }

            writer.write(prod.toString());
            writer.newLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeWriter(writer);
    }
  }

  public void closeWriter(BufferedWriter bw) {
    try {
        if (bw != null) {
            bw.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void closeReader(BufferedReader br) {
    try {
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the controller for the `KeywordPanel`:

```
 public class KeywordPanelController {

  public static class RemoveAction extends TextAction {

    private CSVFileController controller;

    private Product product;

    public RemoveAction(String name, CSVFileController controller,
            Product product) {
        super(name);
        this.controller = controller;
        this.product = product;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JTextComponent textField = (JTextField) getFocusedComponent();

        if (!textField.isEditable()) {

            product.getCategories().remove(textField.getText().trim());
            product.setCategories(product.getCategories());
            controller.adjustProductCategories(product);
            textField.setText("");
            textField.setEditable(true);
        }
    }
  }

  public static class TextFieldMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

    private JTextField textField;

    public TextFieldMouseAdapter(JTextField textField) {
        this.textField = textField;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        textField.setSelectionColor(new Color(142, 15, 6));
        textField.setSelectedTextColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        textField.setSelectionStart(0);
        textField.setSelectionEnd(textField.getText().trim().length());
    }
  }

  public static class SaveAndCloseAction extends AbstractAction {

    private JTextField[] textFields;

    private Product product;

    private CSVFileController controller;

    private Dialog dialog;

    public SaveAndCloseAction(String name, CSVFileController controller,
            Dialog dialog, Product product, JTextField[] textFields) {
        super(name);
        this.controller = controller;
        this.textFields = textFields;
        this.product = product;
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (JTextField textField : textFields) {
            if (new ValidateString().validate(textField.getText().trim())) {
                categories.add(textField.getText().trim());
            }
        }

        product.setCategories(categories);

        controller.adjustProductCategories(product);

        dialog.getDialog().dispose();
    }

  }
}
```

The `Product` class which is a POJO. I'm not entirely sure if this should be considered a model class or not.

```
public class Product {

  private Supplier supplier;

  private List<String> categoryList;

  private int minQty, qtyOnHand, orderQty;

  private double cost;

  private String productDescription, id;

  public Product(Supplier supplier, String id, String productDescription,
        int qtyOnHand, int minQty, double cost, int orderQty,
        List<String> categories) {

    this.supplier = supplier;
    this.qtyOnHand = qtyOnHand;
    this.orderQty = orderQty;
    this.id = id;
    this.minQty = minQty;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
    this.categoryList = categories;
  }

  public Product(Supplier supplier, String id, String productDescription,
        int qtyOnHand, int minQty, double cost, int orderQty) {

    this.supplier = supplier;
    this.qtyOnHand = qtyOnHand;
    this.orderQty = orderQty;
    this.id = id;
    this.minQty = minQty;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
  }

  public Product(String id, String productDescription, int qtyOnHand,
        int minQty, double cost, int orderQty) {
    this.qtyOnHand = qtyOnHand;
    this.orderQty = orderQty;
    this.id = id;
    this.minQty = minQty;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
  }

  public int getQtyOnHand() {
    return qtyOnHand;
  }

  public void setQtyOnHand(int qtyOnHand) {
    this.qtyOnHand = qtyOnHand;
  }

  public int getOrderQty() {
    return orderQty;
  }

  public void setOrderQty(int orderQty) {
    this.orderQty = orderQty;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public double getCost() {
    return cost;
  }

  public void setCost(double cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
  }

  public String getProductDescription() {
    return productDescription;
  }

  public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
  }

  public int getMinQty() {
    return minQty;
  }

  public void setMinQty(int minQty) {
    this.minQty = minQty;
  }

  public List<String> getCategories() {
    return categoryList;
  }

  public void setCategories(List<String> categories) {
    this.categoryList = categories;
  }

  public Supplier getSupplier() {
    return supplier;
  }

  public void setSupplier(Supplier supplier) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
  }

  public boolean isCategorized() {
    if (categoryList == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.append(id).append(",").append(productDescription).append(",")
            .append(qtyOnHand).append(",").append(minQty).append(",")
            .append(cost).append(",").append(orderQty);

    if (isCategorized()) {
        for (String category : categoryList) {
            builder.append(",").append(category);
        }

    }

    return builder.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me start with something good: the names of the variables are good. Even if there is no recognizable package organization: I have seen more bad code from entry-level programmers.

If ever there is any AWT/Swing job, I'd love to use NetBeans as UI-Designer, and you would love it. But hey, to code everything on your own is ok to learn, I think.

Let's get to the critiques:

1. The name of the class `CreateAndShowUI` tries to explain what the implementation does. This hurt particularly the [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) and a few principles of SOLID.
2. The fonts inside of `CreateAndShowUI` should be fields, if you place it into a interface you don't need to write `public static final` because they are immanent by interfacefields.
3. Have you ever thought about extending the `MainPanel` from `JFrame`? I think the separation of a instance of `MainPanel` and `JFrame` is unnecessary. If you do so, please rename `MainPanel` to `MainFrame`. Also, `ButtonPanel` can extend `JPanel` and `MenuBar` can extend `JMenuBar`.
4. Some of the fields in `MainPanel` can be final fields. You don't need a `createMainPanel` function.

   A short example:

   ```
   private final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout(...));
   private final JTable table = new JTable(new ProductTableModel());
   private final JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table, ...);
   private final JButton xButton = new JButton(new CloseAction("X"));
   ```
5. In `Model`, the `productList` should be a variable in the method `addProduct`, not a field. `supplierProductList` should have a `Set` instead of a `List` as a value.
6. The `CSVFileController` is not thread-safe. If you doubleclick too fast on `adjustProductCategories`, the line `writer = new BufferedWriter(...)` creates two instances, but the field `writer` will hold only one instance. So `closeWriter(writer);` will executed twice to the `writer` you created at last and the writer of the first click will never be closed!
7. `Product` is not just a POJO; you created a perfect java-bean. One problem: No one expected to have called `isCategorized` if you call `toString`. This is an implementation detail you should hide. Inline `categoryList==null` in `toString` please, so everyone is allowed to throw `NotImplementedException` in  `isCategorized` without throwing it in the `toString` method too. But keep the method `isCategorized` as it is.

   If any class (i.e. `SpecialProduct`) implements `Product` who has a special kind of `isCategorized`, then `toString` may return wrong values. This would be a bug inside `SpecialProduct` but it's a very bad leak in the design.

Comment: Thank You for your response, I will be working on this first thing tomorrow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320588/interfaces-with-static-fields-in-java-for-sharing-constants/320642#320642       According to this, an interface with only fields is considered bad practice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-the-program  According to this, extending or not extending a container is based on preference

Comment: @CharlesSexton I confirm to use constants in interfaces that are implemented is bad practice. But if we never implement the interface the arguments are reduced: 1. The duplicated JavaDoc is no argument anymore because there is only one documentation.2.The instanceof-smell is no argument because if noone implement the interface you can not call "instance-of" on the instance.3.The argument "if in a future release the class is modified" but no argument anymore because its not part of a official api for 3rd partys. 
The argument that its not the intend of an interface i say: Correct, but its SOLID

Comment: @CharlesSexton The extending or not extending argument is based of the open-close-principle + the request to change the core-behave of the class at runtime. But as we dont need to change the core-behave of the iframe (except the constructor) its ok i think.

Comment: I completely understand what you mean by the JFrame now, thank you for clarifying that.....

Comment: is this what you mean by not implementing the interface? import static package.interface;          Could I implement an interface if needed even with the non implemented interface?

Comment: #6 would you provide a lock and unlock or just rewrite the method all together?

Comment: #7 would you still remove the isCategorized method even if it used in another part of the application as well?

Comment: #6 i would use the CSV-Library from apache-commons, they fixed bugs we wont find in 100 years. But to let you learn i would write a `synchronized(this){...}` around the whole methodcode of `updateModel`. This will hold the execution if any other execution is in the block for the instance **this**.

Comment: @CharlesSexton By *not implementing* the interface i now understand your confusion, sorry. I meant that the interface itself is well implemented, but real classes do never inherit this interface using the keyword `implements` in the class-signature.